# Переходные-переходные глаголы

Tags: орфография

Что значит количественно-разделительные значение?

Answer (score 3):

Количественно-разделительное значение имеют дополнения при переходных глаголах.  Родительный разделительный( родительный количественный,родительный части) указывает на то, что предмет подвергается действию не во всем объеме или является объектом интенсивного действия.

Выпить воды, прикупить тетрадей, надавать советов.